If $f(z)$ and $f(\overline z)$ are analytic in a domain D, then f(z) is only a constant function in D
In the process of trying to show that $f(z)$ is constant given that $f(z)$ and $f(\overline z)$ are analytic in a domain, I came up with a question that left me confused.
Suppose we have a function $f(z) = 5x + i5y$ and $f(\overline z)$= $5x - i5y$ we are able to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are equal since:
For $f(z)$:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 5 = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
For $f(\overline z)$:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = 5 = -\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = 0 = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}$$
So in this case $f(z)$ and $f(\overline z)$ are both analytic but $f(z)$ is not constant.
What have I missed and where is my error?

The first of your second set of Cauchy-Riemann equations is wrong.

@JulioPuerta can you kindly elaborate?

If $g(x+iy)=5x-i5y$, then $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=5$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-5$, which are not equal. You are comparing $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$ and $ -\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}$, which makes no sense.

@JulioPuerta I thought it would be $\frac{∂u}{∂x}$ = -$\frac{∂v}{∂y}$ since the conjugate causes the partial derivatives to change the value for the Cauchy-riemann equation

No, the equations stay the same.

I think there's a little confusion over exactly what "$f(\overline{z})$ is analytic" means.

Why is the question being downvoted? What can I do to improve it?

For $$f(\bar z)=u(x,y)-iv(x,y),$$ it needs to satisfy $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (-v)}{\partial y}$$ to ensure that it is analytic.
In your example, $u(x,y)=5x$, $v(x,y)=5y$, so $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=5\neq-5=\frac{\partial (-v)}{\partial y}.$$ Therefore $f(\bar z)$ is not analytic.
Indeed, in order for $f(z)$ to be an analytic function, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}.$$ And in order for $f(\bar z)$ to be an analytic function, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial (-v)}{\partial y}.$$ So $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v}{\partial y},$$ that is, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0.$$ From another Cauchy-Riemann equation, $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=0.$$ So $u$ is a constant. And the same goes for $v$.

Thank you for your response. I just realised I factored in the negative twice in my second set of Cauchy Riemann equations.
